# My npm sql query results are formatted in JSON but I need them to be stringify

Tags: sql, json, node.js

This is a simple example of connecting to a SQL DB and making an SQL select query on the EMPLOYEE table.  In npm 2.1.8 the results were returned in a stringify format but now it is being returned on multiple rows for each record.  I have provided the code I am using and an example of the results as well as an example how I would like the results returned.

```
const sql = require('mssql')
//const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')

const dbConfig = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'LWWEBAPP'
};

function getEmp() {
    const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
    //var req = new sql.Request(conn);

    sql.connect(dbConfig, err => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
          }

        const request = new sql.Request()
        request.stream = true
        request.query('select * FROM EMPLOYEE') 

        request.on('recordset', columns => {
            //console.log(columns) 
        })

        request.on('row', row => {
            console.log(row) 
        })

        request.on('error', err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
        })

        request.on('done', result => {
            //console.log(result) 
        })
    })

    sql.on('error', err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
    })
}
getEmp();
```

This is the results I get back:

```
  {    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER: '100',
       FIRST_NAME: 'Jim',
       LAST_NAME: Smith, }
  {    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER: '101',
       FIRST_NAME: 'John',
       LAST_NAME: Smith }
  {    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER: '102',
       FIRST_NAME: 'Sue',
       LAST_NAME: Smith }
```

I would like the results on one line for each record:

```
[ {EMPLOYEE_NUMBER: '100', FIRST_NAME: 'Jim', LAST_NAME: 'Smith'} .
  {EMPLOYEE_NUMBER: '101', FIRST_NAME: 'John', LAST_NAME: 'Smith'} .
  {EMPLOYEE_NUMBER: '102', FIRST_NAME: 'Sue', LAST_NAME: 'Smith'} ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to:

```
request.on('row', row => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify);
})
```

You would get result like this, but without array closure

```js
var rows = [{
    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER: '100',
    FIRST_NAME: 'Jim',
    LAST_NAME: "Smith",
  },
  {
    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER: '101',
    FIRST_NAME: 'John',
    LAST_NAME: "Smith"
  },
  {
    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER: '102',
    FIRST_NAME: 'Sue',
    LAST_NAME: "Smith"
  }
]

rows.forEach(function(elem) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(elem));//{"EMPLOYEE_NUMBER":"100","FIRST_NAME":"Jim","LAST_NAME":"Smith"}
});

alert(JSON.stringify(rows));
```

If you wanna see array you must collect all rows of result into array and after it call `JSON.stringify(yourArray)`

Comment: Pavlo, if you can provide a little more clarity.  I am having difficult getting this to work.  This is the result I get when I replace console.log(row) with console.log(JSON.stringify) [Function: stringify]
[Function: stringify]
[Function: stringify]
[Function: stringify]
[Function: stringify]

Comment: @joey.coyle tou have wrong replace. Right is  `console.log(JSON.stringify(row));`